# Setting javafx linechart line width

Tags: java, css, javafx, linechart

I am trying to embed a JavaFX line chart in a Swing application. It is showing up fine inside my application, but when I try to change the lines widths, I get stuck. I don't know how the CSS styling is supposed to work. I see `LineChart` has a `setStyle()` method which I tried to utilize from an example:

```
lineChart.setStyle(".chart-series-line {    \n"
        + "    -fx-stroke-width: 2px;\n"
        + "}");
```

But no change is shown. I then tried to lookup my series :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= value; i++)
     lineChart.lookupAll(".series" + i).forEach(n -> n.setStyle("-fx-stroke-width: 3px;"));
```

Now the lines changed width vertically but not horizontally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems my problem came from the symbols.

I had 365 items on the x axis, which made it paint the symbols on top of each other making it look like i really thick line. I could fix this by disabling the symbols

```
lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style in your CSS file :

```
.thick-chart .chart-series-line {    
-fx-stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

and use StyleClass instead of Style :

```
lineChart.getStyleClass().add("thick-chart");
```